# How to deal with boolean value from form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, elixir, phoenix-framework

we use checkbox to submit a boolean data in a form.

In rails, when submit the form, a string with `"1"` or `"0"` will be submitted to the controller.

In phoenix, when submit the form, a string with `"true"` or `"false"` will be submitted to the controller.

It's fine if we directly create object in the database. Either of value will be store as boolean correctly.

But if we need to use the boolean value in our logic, what's the best way to do it?

1. Convert to boolean:

```
    # Ruby code
    def create
      admin = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(param[:admin])
      if admin
          ....
      end
    end
```

2. Directly use as string:

```
    # Elixir code
    def create(conn, params) do
      case params[:admin] do
        "true" -> do something
        _ -> do others
      end
    end
```

3. Other better ways?

Answer (score 3):

[`String.to_existing_atom/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html?#to_existing_atom/1) is your friend.

Both `true` and `false` are *atoms*, namely a syntactic sugar for `:true` and `:false`. That is because in [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) they are atoms.

```rb
:true == true
#⇒ true
:false == false
#⇒ true

String.to_existing_atom "true"
#⇒ true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you prefer option 1? Why?

Comment: I prefer the explicit conversion to an atom, not `cast`. But `cast` is also better because a) 2. is too error-prone for malicious input, and even if the second case clause would be corrected to `"false"`, dialyzer would complain about `no return`, and b) the intent is clearly to cast, not to match whatever was received from the wild. Also, I have no idea what this `Foo::Bar.cast/1` does, and I know `String.to_existing_atom/1` just works.

Comment: My question is focusing on design decision. 1) Use string in controller 2) Convert to Boolean in controller(Don't care which method) 3) In Plug/before_action maybe?

Comment: Not 1) because as I said it’s error-prone against the malicious input. I would not do it in `Plug` either because controllers expect to receive the query as is, not with something already converted to atom (which is not representable in JSON/HTTP query.).